# Confusion about different clobber description for arm inline assembly

Tags: gcc, arm, inline-assembly, arm64

I'm learning ARM inline assembly, and is confused about a very simple function: assign the value of `x` to `y` (both are `int` type), **on arm32 and arm64 why different clobber description required?**

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <arm_neon.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void asm_test()
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 0;

#ifdef __aarch64__
    asm volatile(
        "mov %w[in], %w[out]"
        : [out] "=r"(y)
        : [in] "r"(x)
        : "r0" // r0 not working, but r1 or x1 works
    );
#else
    asm volattile(
        "mov %[in], %[out]"
        : [out] "=r"(y)
        : [in] "r"(x)
        : "r0"    // r0 works, but r1 not working
    );
#endif
    printf("y is %d\n", y);
}

int main() {
    arm_test();

    return 0;
}
```

Tested on my rooted android phone, for arm32, `r0` generates correct result but `r1` won't. For arm64, `r1` or `x1` generate correct result, and `r0` won't. Why on arm32 and arm64 they are different? What is the concrete rule for this and where can I find it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**ARM / AArch64 syntax is `mov dst, src`**

Your asm statement only works if the compiler happens to pick the same register for both `"=r"` output and `"r"` input (or something like that, given extra copies of `x` floating around).

**Different clobbers simply perturb the compiler's register-allocation choices.**  Look at the generated asm (`gcc -S` or on https://godbolt.org/, especially with `-fverbose-asm`.)

Undefined Behaviour from getting the constraints mismatched with the instructions in the template string can still happen to work; never assume that an asm statement is correct just because it works with one set of compiler options and surrounding code.

---

BTW, **x86 AT&T syntax** does use `mov src, dst`, and many GNU C inline-asm examples / tutorials are written for that.  Assembly language is specific to the ISA and the toolchain, but a lot of architectures have an instruction called `mov`.  Seeing a `mov` does *not* mean this is an ARM example.

Also, you don't actually need a `mov` instruction to use inline asm to copy a valid.  Just tell the compiler you want the input to be in the same register it picks for the output, whatever that happens to be:

```
  // not volatile: has no side effects and produces the same output if the input is the same; i.e. the output is a pure function of the input.
  asm ("" 
        : "=r"(output)      // pick any register
        : "0"(input)        // pick the same register as operand 0
        : // no clobbers
    );
```

Comment: Thanks! My code does use wrong syntax.  Fixing that it generate correct result.